# flow type annotation for children react elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Is there a better way to type-annotate `children` ?

```
type FilterLinkProps={
  filter:State$VisibilityFilter,
  children:any
};

const FilterLink = ({
  filter,
  children
}:FilterLinkProps) => {
  return (
    <a href='#'
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        store.dispatch(({
          type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
          filter
        }:Action$VisibilityFilter));
      }}
    >
    {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like.

From the official [React libdef](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L159):

```
declare module react {
  declare var Children: any;
  ...
}
```

and then

```
declare function cloneElement<Config> (
    element: React$Element<Config>,
    attributes: $Shape<Config>,
    children?: any
  ): React$Element<Config>;
```

Answer (score 28):

**Flow v0.53** supports `children` out of the box!!

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children?: React.Node,
};
```

More info read [official docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/children/) or the following [blog post](https://medium.com/flow-type/even-better-support-for-react-in-flow-25b0a3485627) about it.

**For older versions** of flow you can do the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import type { Children } from 'react';
type Props = {
  children?: Children,
};
const SampleText = (props: Props) => (
  <div>{props.children}</div>
);
```

Either case `children` should be declared as a [nullable](https://flowtype.org/docs/nullable-types.html#_) type.

It looks like that they will move some pieces forward with the arrival of fiber, hope they do!

Following the discussion in [github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1964)

**Cheat sheet:** http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2016/06/flow-type-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

```
type Text = string | number;
type Fragment = Iterable<Node>;
type ReactNode = React$Element<any>
  | Text
  | Fragment;
```

`ReactNode` should be the type of children, but caveat emptor.

Source: I've seen this construction in some github issues on the flow repo, I believe.